# Trigger window.onload when only some resources are loaded

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I have a following html. I know that `window.onload` will be invoked when all resources are loaded. In my case, resources are *.js files. How can I trigger `window.onload` right after the first five *js files are loaded?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>My body</h1>
    </body>
    <script src="file1.js"></script>
    <script src="file2.js"></script>
    <script src="file3.js"></script>
    <script src="file4.js"></script>
    <script src="file5.js"></script>
    <!--I want to trigger window.onload here-->
    <script src="file6.js"></script>
    <script src="file7.js"></script>
    <script src="file8.js"></script>
    <script src="file9.js"></script>
    <script src="file10.js"></script>

    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            console.log('window.onload');
        };
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: how about invoking file6 -till- file10 inside `window.onload` !!

Comment: do you mean load external js files inside function like this?https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/28/the-best-way-to-load-external-javascript/

Comment: if it worked with you, yes you can , it depends on what are you tryin to do, .., you may find shorter ways though